# Dynamic html text box width Angular

Tags: html, css

I m using normal html input and i m specifying the width and height as percentage, it looks good and works fine when i view it in my laptop but when i view it in a monitor, the alignment differs

this is an angular app.. not sure whether it has any relation with flexible design

Edit 1:

This is the code from W3 schools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>

<h2>Setting the Viewport</h2>
<p>This example does not really do anything, other than showing you how to add the viewport meta element.</p>

<label>Test </label>
<input type='text' style="width:200px; height:14px"> 

</body>
</html>
```

I just copied it in the responsive design and added a textbox of fixed width and height. when i run it in W3schools and shrink the size of the window.. the content from the example,changes accordingly but my textbox remains fixed size and not adjusting

Comment: Could you add some more context? Like what it's currently doing (we can't see that without your added style classes etc) and what you expect it to do (we don't know what you mean considering the previous statement). Otherwise it makes it pretty difficult to troubleshoot as just guess work, but it's not an angular thing...

Comment: @ChrisW. i edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You had given the fixed with `200px`. That it is always fixed.

```
<input type='text' style="width:200px; height:14px">
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .col-25, .col-75, input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: how to make it responsive.. do i need to give it in rem or % . could you please update with answer

Comment: You can use `@media` in css.